# Asp Web Api async action - 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've got some api controller with this action:

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController {
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostActionAsync(string confirmKey)
    {
         return await Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew( () =>
               {
                  var result = GetSomeResult(confirmKey);
                  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
               });
    }
}
```

And here is my api routing confuguration:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

When I try to make any Post/Get Requests to this action, it's returns '404' error. How can I fix it? All other not-async actions in this controller works fine.

UPD. JS query:

```
$.ajax({
        url: Url + '/api/Proxy/PostActionAsync',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { confirmKey: that.confirmKey },                  
        dataType: 'json',                   
        xhrFields: {  withCredentials: true  },
        success: function (data) {
            ............
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             ............
        }                        
});
```

UPD. Resolved by adding `[FromBody]` to my parameters in action method just like in J. Steen's answer, now it's look's like

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController {
       public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostActionAsync([FromBody]string confirmKey)
        {
            var someModel = new SomeResultModel(User.Identity.Name);
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => someModel.PrepareModel(confirmKey));

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, someModel);
        }
    }
```

And it works!

Comment: Post your `ActionResult` Method and Controller name too. If possible your async calling Jquery too., :)

Comment: @IgorKonopko: Try to mark the action with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: it's should be action-based routing, so it's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The routing configuration for Web API works a little differently than MVC.

Try

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Note the missing `{action}` as that is resolved by Web API at call-time, automagically, depending on the HTTP verb you use for your request.

Consider [this article on Web API routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) which lists (as an example):

```
HTTP Method  URI Path            Action           Parameter
GET          api/products        GetAllProducts   (none)
GET          api/products/4      GetProductById   4
DELETE       api/products/4      DeleteProduct    4
```

In your case, the async version of an action is also resolved automatically.

```
POST         api/products        PostActionAsync  (Post data)
```

Since we now know the controller name, requests would be like:

```
GET api/proxy
GET api/proxy/4
POST api/proxy (with post data)
```

---

**Edit**:

After additional research (brief, I admit) I have found the issue.

You need to add `[FromBody]` infront of your in-parameter.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostActionAsync([FromBody] string confirmKey)
```

This, combined with sending *just* the value (no wrapping json) works wonders. Set content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of json, and send your parameter as `"=" + that.confirmKey`.

**Alternative**:

If you don't want to fiddle around with content-types and prefixing =-signs, just send it as part of the querystring. Forget the `[FromBody]` and the rest. Call

```
/api/Proxy/PostActionAsync?confirmKey=' + that.confirmKey
```

[Additional, exhaustive information in this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx).

Comment: I've changed routing as at youre example, also my client ajax url changed to ServerUrl+ '/api/Proxy?action=PostActionAsync', now it return's 500 (Internal Server Error). Is it meen that I should use only one get/post/put action in one api controller?

Comment: The convention is to only use one POST per controller. Also, ?action=PostActionAsync probably won't work well either, I'm sorry to say. =/

Comment: I am wildly confused. If you want action-based routing, my answer is wrong. Your route-config needs to be as you originally stated it.

Comment: you mean like in top post?

Comment: I've been trying your code, creating a controller with a post async action, and your original routing configuration. For me, it works just as expected. Are you *sure* the `Url` parameter you paste infront of your `api/Proxy/PostActionAsync` has the correct value?

Comment: yes, url parameter is correct, and I thing that it's can't be found because off cross-domain requests. =(

Comment: What if you just put `data: { that.confirmKey }` without the property qualifier name? =)

Comment: I tried to create another async action in this controller, and made request to it, that action has no parameters to get, and it still not works.  Does your test action works with cross-domain requests?

Comment: I don't have several domains to test with, in my current environment, I'm afraid. If you don't get another, working answer (or solve it yourself), I'm having a look at it later, after work.

Comment: Ok, also I'll try to change something with 'data: { that.confirmKey }'

Comment: @IgorKonopko Solved the issue locally. See if you can, too?

Comment: Well, i've just add [FromBody] to my parameters and live JS code same as it was, and now it's works, thank's you a lot. =) Well, now it's can't get HttpContext.Current information, but this is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is that change possible?

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostActionAsync()
{
    var result = await GetSomeResult();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
}
```

Comment: 'CreateResponse()' returns 'HttpResponseMessage', which can't be converted to 'Task<HttpResponseMessage>'

Comment: `async Task<string> WaitAsynchronouslyAsync() { await Task.Delay(10000); return "Finished"; }` This is example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx).

Comment: If your `PrepareModel` method return bool you can change: `var eventModel = new EventResultModel(...); var result = await eventModel.PrepareModel(confirmKey)); if (result) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, eventModel); } else { ...error response... }`

Comment: but when I try to make Get request to this action, it's says that action allowed only for Post requests